# Create View: All Active Questions tagged with any of my Favorite Tags

Tags: feature-request, support

The Questions > Active view only allows me 2 options:

- display all active questions
- display all active questions under a single tag

How do I display all active questions under all my favorite tags? If it's not possible, can we have something for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search for multiple tags too in `\tagged` page: using this syntax `tag1+or+tag2+or+tag3`

E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+or+vb6+or+excel?sort=active

But yes we can not browse by our favorite tags directly. We have to add it manually. But we can use wildcard like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*sql*+or+vb6+or+*excel*